# Is there a Powershell equivalent to Diskpart's "gpt attributes"?

Tags: partitioning, powershell, gpt

I need to remake several batch scripts that use diskpart for partitioning in Powershell. One of them "hides" the Windows recovery partition thusly:

```
select disk 0
select partition 4
set id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
remove
```

I've fount Powershell commandlets for everything except line 4. This line sets the attribute that simultaneously marks the partition as required and prevents automatic drive letter assignment. But I can't find a way to do that in Powershell - there simply seems to be no equivalent to "gpt attributes=".

Does anyone know how to achieve this in Powershell?

EDIT:

I think I found a partial solution. For reference, my Powershell code looks like this:

In an earlier script, the recovery partition was created:

```
param(
[int]$DiskNr = 0
)

Clear-Disk -number $DiskNr -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false
Initialize-Disk -Number $DiskNr -PartitionStyle GPT
New-Partition -DiskNumber $DiskNr -Size 850MB -DriveLetter R -GptType "{de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac}"
Format-Volume -DriveLetter R -FileSystem NTFS -Force -NewFileSystemLabel "Recovery"
```

Here we already take care of line 3 in the original diskpart script by setting the GPT Type to mark it as a recovery partition.

Later on I want to hide it (which is what the original diskpart script was doing), so I'm using:

```
Set-Partition -DriveLetter R -NoDefaultDriveLetter $True
Get-Partition -DriveLetter R | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -accesspath "R:"
```

The first line here *partially* does what the "gpt attribute="-command in the original diskpart script did; it prevents the system from automatically assigning a drive letter to the partition. I still haven't found a solution for the other half of the command however: Marking the partition as necessary for the Windows installation. I'm not actually entirely sure I need that in the first place, so perhaps I'm already done.

Comment: can you show the powershell commands you used for the other lines?

Comment: @phuclv I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: "_I still haven't found a solution for the other half of the command however: Marking the partition as necessary for the Windows installation_" Unless that's referring to the GPT Attribute, only that and the GUID is what sets the partition as required by Windows installer, as the installer looks for three GUIDs, the EFI, normal data, and WinRE partitions - as long as those three are correctly preconfigured, the installer uses them as is. Unless manually copying data to the WinRE partition, no drive letter needs to be assigned

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when creating a script to make a Windows recovery partition (after resizing the disk). I also don't know of any native PowerShell command syntax to set attributes, but I was able to accomplish what I wanted:

```
$recoverySizeMiB = 720

$drive = Get-Partition -DriveLetter C

$partitionSupportedSize = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber $drive.DiskNumber -PartitionNumber $drive.PartitionNumber

$newSize = $partitionSupportedSize.SizeMax - ($recoverySizeMiB * 1MB)

Resize-Partition -DiskNumber $drive.DiskNumber -PartitionNumber $drive.PartitionNumber -Size $newSize

$recoveryPartition = New-Partition -DiskNumber $drive.DiskNumber -UseMaximumSize -GptType "{de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac}"

Format-Volume -Partition $recoveryPartition -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Recovery" -Force

$null = @"
select disk $($drive.DiskNumber)
select partition $($partitionRecovery.PartitionNumber)
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
assign letter=R
exit
"@ | diskpart.exe
```

This works because we have the disk and partition numbers from previous steps. We can pipe the input into diskpart and be on our way.

Cheers!

Comment: Unless manually copying data to the WinRE partition, no drive letter needs to be assigned, as the installer only cares about the correct GUID and GPT Attribute being assigned

Comment: I needed the drive letter to copy my recovery partition files. Feel free to omit it.